# How can I setup a link without exposing the link itself?

Tags: url, post, hyperlink

Actually its not actually a problem, but I'm thinking and searching for it for a while.
When we use php and to setup some link we can use something like-

```
    <a href="index.php?action=something&something=someotherthing">some link</a>
```

in this way anyone can see what is going on by looking at the url. Is there any possible way to keep it hidden like the `POST` method of the `form` element?
I don't want user to modify and play around with my parameters and values. Lets guess I don't want to encrypt the values and parameters and I can't use `form` element as they should be pure links. And also what if I don't want to use url rewriting engine.

Any ideas from the experts?

edit:

I forgot to mention another most important thing that I need to get the parameters and the values I want to pass through that link and do some stuffs in the page i'm linking to.
thanks again.

Comment: Don't confuse that by hiding data in a post request, that it might be safer. Just because it's posting instead of getting, it doesn't mean that people can't still mangle it. There's an excellent plugin for firefox called Tamper Data that makes this just as trivial as editing it as if it's in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden form

```
<form action="realurl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="value1"></input>
</form>
<a onclick="forms[0].submit();" href="http://fake">link text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Its close what i'm looking for. I want- when a user click on a link, that links is gonna open up and I want to pass some parameters through this link. And as this link is open and anyone can see it by looking at the toolbar, anyone can modify it (i also tried it in some places). I don't want to let my user to do so. And for this I'm thinking if I can make the parameters hidden like we see in the post method. We are passing data through it but we can't see them. Thanks

Comment: Edited the answer. This one should be closer.

Comment: This one is really closer. But I wanted to use this in place like navigation or something. What do you think of using a form there?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Links are navigation. What do you mean by navigation? Please refer to specific html constructs. Or better yet, provide a source code snippet of what you are currently doing.